# Customize onclick event in pesdk android library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

In my project, I came across an issue related to a photo editing library that's used in both Android and iOS. Specifically, I needed to add a feature where, upon choosing a filter from the filterToolPanel, I could capture the selected filter through an onClick event.

In the iOS version, I had access to a method called "filterSelectedClosure," which allowed me to retrieve the selected filter. However, I faced a challenge in the Android version.

I had successfully overridden the "FilterToolPanel" class to customize its behavior, I was encountering difficulties in integrating this customized class into the editor activity.

```
class CustomFilterToolPanel(stateHandler: StateHandler, val context: Context) : FilterToolPanel(stateHandler) {

    override fun onItemClick(item: AbstractIdItem?) {

        // Your custom behavior here
        context.toast("this filter clicked")

        super.onItemClick(item)
    }
}
```

But i don't know how to link this overridden class to the photo editor activity.

This is library documentation link: https://img.ly/docs/pesdk/android/getting-started/integration/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a better question for the developer of the library. If you want help here, at minimum you will need to identify the library, such as via a link to a GitHub repository.